# How do I know why I failed the level in Theme Hospital

Tags: theme-hospital

I'm currently playing theme hospital on PC. I'm up to level 5 or 6 I think and I've failed the level a few times. My problem is that I'm not really sure *why* I'm failing the level. I get to watch the little video and see the newspaper headline but it's still not obvious.

I found this video:

It shows the various failure clips, and the description suggests that there are 7 possible failures and each has a few possible headlines (see below).

**Failure #1**. Headlines:

- DOC SHOCK HORROR
- CREEPY GP PLAYS GOD
- PRANKENSTEIN SHOCK
- WHAT WAS ON LAB SLAB?
- RAID HALTS RISKY RESEARCH

**Failure #2**. Headlines:

- DR-UNK AS A SKUNK
- SMASHED SURGEON
- CAROUSING CONSULTANT
- SURGICAL SNIFTER
- SURGEON SWILLS IT
- SURGICAL SPIRITS

**Failure #3**. Headlines:

- SURGIN' SURGEON
- DOCTOR PANTSDOWN
- DOCTOR GOING DOWN
- INSATIABLE SURGEON

**Failure #4**. Headlines:

- DOCTOR-ING THE FIGURES
- ORGAN-ISED CRIME
- BANK BYPASS OPERATION
- FUND HOLDING GP

**Failure #5**. Headlines:

- MEDICAL BOFFIN RAIDS COFFIN
- DOC EMPTIES GRAVES
- CAUGHT WITH CORPSE
- DR DEATH'S DAY OF RECKONING
- TERMINAL MALPRACTICE
- DOCTOR'S DIG DENOUNCED

**Failure #6**. Headlines:

- DOC STITCHED UP!
- SLACK QUACK
- DAMNING DIAGNOSIS
- CLUMSY CONSULTANT

**Failure #7**. Headlines:

- DOC FEELS AT LOOSE END
- SURGEON 'OPERATES' HIMSELF
- BOG BISHOP-BASHING
- DOCTOR'S HANDLE SCANDAL
- MEDIC MAKES A MESS

I'm failing with #2 but it'd be great to have a complete list. So, **what is the cause of each of these failure conditions?**

Comment: Failure #4 sounds financial. So I'm guessing that's if you get in too much debt.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about failure #4 now. I just got myself into over $1,000,000 worth of debt and it didn't fail me. :S

Comment: Failure #2 sounds like being drunk... are you drinking alcohol?

Comment: @Catija I'm not drinking alcohol. I can if you think it'll help ;)

As far as I know my hospital is also alcohol-free. But those doctors are crafty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think those failure conditions are just random headlines that doesn't mention why you lost.
If you click on this button in the lower right corner: [image]

then you get to a "Winning condition" screen, where you and 3 other hospitals are trying to win. The first hospital who reached 100% in both people cured, money, and hospital rating will win the scenario.

If an AI hospital reaches that before you, I think you will lose and will be shown some random news headline.

Comment: I'd like to second this. I haven't been able to find any solid sources stating that one of the headlines corresponds to a certain way of failure. From my experience playing the game, you only lose when a different hospital reaches the goal before you.

Comment: I've seen the competing hospitals but never paid too much attention to them. I never would have thought of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The game is lost when, at the end of the year, you have any goal below an established threshold. The headlines are random, so you'll have to check your progress report status before you lose.

Below a certain threshold, the bar will turn red and will grow as you get farther from the goal. If it is at 100% at the end of the year, you will lose the game.

See the following example with the bank balance goal:

1. Congratulations, you have enough money to win if you meet your other goals:

   [image: Green bar at 100%]
2. The green bar has decreased. You haven't enough money to win:

   [image: Green bar decreasing]
3. The green bar has decreased below 0%, has turned red and is increasing. If you continue losing money you will lose the game:

   [image: Red bar increasing]
4. You have lost more money and the red bar has reached 100%. You will lose at the end of the year (with a random video/headline) if you don't increase your money:

   [image: Red bar at 100%]

Comment: wow, awesome answer! thank you! really should be marked as "Accepted".